# What is the SRID of census.gov shapefiles?

Tags: postgis, census, coordinate-system, srid

I downloaded the county files from:

http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2011/main

I cannot figure out what **SRID** to use with them. When I am trying to generate a class file from `./manage.py ogrinspect ...`, I get an SRID of `-1` in the polygon field. I don't think that this is right.

GDAL gave me the **Proj4** of `+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs`.

I know an SRID of -1 means unknown. Wouldn't that make my geometries useless? How can I figure out what SRID to use?

I am really new to GIS. I already miss the days when the Earth was flat.

This may also be useful:

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
                                         postgis_full_version                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.8" USE_STATS
(1 row)
```

---

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 0, 'final', 0)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first step to determining the correct projection of any layer, is to find the projection information, if any, that came with your layer.  In the case of a `Shapefile`, like what you downloaded from [Census.gov](http://www.census.gov), that information is contained in a `.prj` file, short for Projection.

Here are the contents of the projection file from the census data:

> GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

The key parts of this, are the first word **GEOGCS** means `Geographic Coordinate System`, the string **DATUM**: `D_North_American_1983`, **SPHERIOD**: `GRS_1980`, and the last part **UNIT**: `Degree`.

These easily match up to the **Proj4** definition that you received: `+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs`

You can see that the datum and ellipsoid, match up to the datum and spheriod in the ".prj".  The `longlat` means `Longitude/Latitude`, which is measured in **Units** of `Degrees`, which matches the ".prj" file.

There are "no defs" because no additional information is necessary to identify the Geographic Coordinate System.

A site to search for spatial references is:  [SpatialReference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org)

The Geographic Coordinate System in NAD 83 is hard to come up with directly, because it is a part of many other projections.

To make it easier, the one you need is [EPSG 4269](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/).

This link presents the spatial reference information in a number of different formats.  The one specifically for [PostGIS](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/postgis/) is:

> INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text,
>   srtext) values ( 94269, 'epsg', 4269, '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80
>   +datum=NAD83 +no_defs ', 'GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS
>   1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]]');

To address your last point regarding the SRID = -1, I think it is important to test your data before you assume they are useless.  Try to bring it up in some GIS software, like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org), or [ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/).  Look at the coordinates that are shown as you move the cursor around.  If you see familiar ranges of numbers, like y = 0 – +90 and x = -180 – +180, you should recognize these as Latitude/Longitude.  Beginning to recognize the coordinate ranges that occur in the common projections and coordinate systems in your area will help you greatly as you move forward in your career.

If you are interested in learning more about projections and coordinate systems, this is a fantastic reference:  A Working Manual ([PDF](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/djvu/PP/PP_1395.pdf)) - John P. Snyder

Comment: I did realize, that I may have asked the wrong question. I asked for fish when I should have asked how to fish. If I search for 'GRS80 NAD83' at http://SpatialReference.org, I get one result that does not look correct.

---

The link you gave for EPSG 4269 has the OpenLayers map display with a bounding box around most of Asia and North Africa. Is this correct or even significant?

Comment: @kzh - I honestly do not know why it is showing that bounding box.  It is not significant though.  The details contained within the spatial reference are what count, and they are correct.

Comment: The degree is slightly off for some reason - why would that be? spatialreference.org has a more accurate listing here: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6867/ , which doesn't exist as an srid in my `spatial_ref_sys` table.

Comment: @GetSpatial - Why did you use 94269 as the SRID instead of 4269? (since 4269 is the EPSG identifier for NAD 83)

Comment: @neubert - I did use SRID 4269.  In the answer, the text string that I pasted in, which includes the references to 94269, is copied from the SRID 4269 string formatted for PostGIS.  I am not sure why it includes that, but there you have it.

Comment: @GetSpatial - From Mr Butler at spatialreference.org "all postgis IDs are prefixed with 9 to ensure that they don't collide with existing postgis IDs."

Comment: @neubert see comment above

Answer (score 3):

@Get Spatial is right and it couldnt have been better answer to this question. in addition to him you can check out spatial_ref_sys before adding any spatial reference.

```
SELECT * FROM
       spatial_ref_sys WHERE auth_srid = 4269;
```

probably you will take sth like this:

```
SRID  | AUTH_NAME  | AUTH_SRID  | SRTEXT
------+------------+------------+-------
4269  |   EPSG     |   1624     | <big SRTEXT string>

SRTEXT = GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 
         1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
         PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
         AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]]

PROJ4TEXT = +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs
```

Spatial_ref_sys is merely a table of known coordinate systems keyed by their SRID. you cabn get more info [here](http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/archives/239)...

- srid: The numeric SRID. This should be the table’s primary key.
- auth_name: An authority name as a string. This is set if this coordinate system is specified by an outside authority such as EPSG.
- auth_srid: The numeric ID of the coordinate system in the above authority’s catalog.
- srtext: The Well-Known-Text (WKT) representation of the coordinate system (as we described in part 4).
- proj4text: The Proj4 representation of the coordinate system.

and last thing is that for loading it to database use this command:

```
shp2pgsql -c -D -s 4269 -I tl_2011_02_anrc.shp myschema.mytable > mysql.sql
psql -d mydb -f mysql.sql
```

i hope it helps you....